# Angular dynamic reactive form: create custom date validation

Tags: angular, validation, date, compare, angular-reactive-forms

I am creating an angular reactive form in the below way.

```
createFormGroup(parameters: any) {
    let group: any = {};
    parameters.forEach(parameter => {
     if (parameter.uiControl === 'DATERANGE') {
      group[parameter.name + '_to'] = parameter.isRequired ? new FormControl(parameter.value || '', [Validators.required]) //create custom validator to compare the 2 date fields
      : new FormControl(parameter.value || '');
      group[parameter.name + '_from'] = parameter.isRequired ? new FormControl(parameter.value || '', [Validators.required])   //create custom validator to compare the 2 date fields
      : new FormControl(parameter.value || '');
     } else {
      group[parameter.name] = parameter.isRequired ? new 
    FormControl(parameter.value || '', Validators.required)
        : new FormControl(parameter.value || '');
     }});    
    return new FormGroup(group);
  }
```

So for ex if we pass parameters as shown below

```
where parameters = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "create_date",
    "displayName": "Create Date",
    "uiControl": "DATERANGE",
    "dataType": "DATE",
  }
]
```

It will create 2 formControls based on the above logic in the `DATERANGE` if condition: `create_date_to` and `create_date_from`

How to apply custom validation in the `createFormGroup` function to set that `create_date_to`shouldnt start before `create_date_from` which are both javascript `date objects`

Answer (score 0):

Your scenario can be achieved through Rxwebvalidators. I have used minDate validator of @rxweb/reactive-form-validators.

```js
RxwebValidators.minDate({fieldName:parameter.name + '_from'})
```

I have set the validator in your 'create_date_from' Formcontrol.

Have a look your code below with my changes:

```js
 group[parameter.name + '_to'] = parameter.isRequired ? new FormControl(parameter.value || '', [Validators.required]) //create custom validator to compare the 2 date fields
      : new FormControl(parameter.value || '', RxwebValidators.minDate({fieldName:parameter.name + '_from'}));
```

Refer the working example on stackblitz link:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-min-date-validator-cross-field?file=src/app/app.component.ts

In the example enter the value in mm/dd/yyyy format. you can change the format based on your need.